# How to reduce the apk size?

Tags: android, sdk

I want to reduce the apk side, for performance ,so how can i do this. any one having idea then please share.

I am using simple build process for building the apk, I am using jpg,png icons for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many things you need to focus for reducing the Apk size like.
Use small size icons or use vector assets
-Reuse the resources
Use progard 
You can also use 
shrinkResouces true
etc
Please check below link

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using png try running an optimizer such as [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/) on your assets.
Enable [Proguard Shrinking](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) on your release apk for a smalles size as well.
Lastly you could follow [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html) advices.

Answer (score 0):

Exit from eclipse.

Copy source folder from workspace to out of it.

Delete bin, gen and libs folder from new folder on out of workspace.

Run eclipse.

Delete app folder ( has copy out of workspace).

Open new project, chose porject of existing source code.

Open source folder until main activity.

Run project.

Now You can get small size apk in Your bin folder.